# mead - is shaking the bottle necessary

Tags: bottling, mead, serving

I have made 2 batches of mead that are now coming to maturity. One at 11 percent, aged for 18 months and one at 18 percent, aged for 3 years.

I notice that both are very clear, beautiful bouquet and clean tasting, but with a bitter aftertaste. When I pour out the last dregs of the bottle into the glass, there is a little turbidity, but also a complete flavor change - there's sweetness added too that offsets the bitterness.

I wasn't expecting sweetness to somehow stratify in the bottle, yet I have this in both meads I've made so far - is this expected?

Comment: I notice that a yeasty pint has a distinct flavor that I would describe partly as sweet.  This may be a clue.

Comment: Thanks Dustin, I've also drank a few easty pints, but I don't think it's the same flavor. The amount of turbidity is very slight - I can still read through the glass, but the flavor is noticabaly sweeter. Enough so that the entire bottle shaken makes for a balanced mead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of such a thing and it's hard to believe that "sweetness" could stratify.  I've never seen that happen with any beverage.  So I'd say no, it's not to be expected.

Comment: Thanks denny. I an understand your reasoning, but I've had the same happen in the 20 or so bottles I've tasted across both batches. Strafitication is common in beverages, just look at multi-layered cocktails, or a black and tan. But from what you say, you've not had this in any of your own meads?

Comment: Not in mead, beer, cider, soda, or anything else.  The reason you have stratification in a black and tan or cocktails is because you're mixing beers of 2 different specific gravities, not because it separates put.